# How to remove power in a modular exponent expression?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I am implementing a [cryptography scheme](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F0-387-34805-0_20.pdf) which involves verifiying some data through the following process:

> Suppose party *A* wants to verify data held by party B 
> **Party A** has: $a^x mod\ N$ 
> **Party *B*** has: $x^{-1}$ *i.e.* modular inverse of $x$ with respect
>   to some $p$ such that $xx^{-1} \equiv 1\ mod\ p$

To carry out the verification, B has to use $a^x \bmod N$ and $x^{-1}$ to attempt creating $a\bmod N$
If $x^{-1}$ is correctly calculated, then the data held by B is verified.
My question is, how can I, using $a^x \bmod N$ and modular inverse $x^{-1}$ attempt to generate $a\bmod N$

Comment: Based on the cryptgraphic scheme detailed here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_20

Comment: Given y, it's quick to get y inverse mod p by the euclidean algorithm on p, y. So take x inverse, compute x, then you know the exponent used

Comment: x is a confidential value only to be known by B. As such, A attempts to regenerate a mod N using his version of x,  a^x mod N and the corresponding x inverse. If 'x' held by B is valid, he should be able to successfully generate a mod N